# Open-source library to generate Ladder Logic diagrams

Tags: open-source, software-development, simulation, 3d

And now I have to generate a  diagram image using that information.

Is there any open-source library to generate a diagram from [Ladder logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_logic)?

Requirements:

- Input: The logic, I can express it in any format, XML or other.
- Output: An image (diagram representing the logic)
- Open source
- Bonus if the layout is nice and space-efficient without making the diagram look too convoluted

Context: I am creating a 3D simulator which teaches to wire [Motor Control](http://www.mikeholt.com/instructor2/img/product/pdf/1245861713sample.pdf). The simulator has all the information about how devices are connected (lights, push buttons, relays, etc), and needs to produce a visual representation of it.

Comment: This question does not have sufficient requirements to be a good question.  "Generate appropriate ladder logic" doesn't say who does the generation, how that agent gets a description of the problem, what the generated ladder logic looks like, ...

Comment: You write "I'm creating", and use the `software-development` tag – so you're obviously looking for some library. But you didn't e.g. include what programming language such library must support – or if you even prefer an "external tool" to be called from your application. So I have to agree with Ira: this question lacks essential details, which makes us unable to give good answers. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185), and see if you can [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: @Izzy: he does say what programming language:  (relay) ladder logic.  This is a family of programming languages widely used in industrial control for factories.  (He doesn't mention a specific dialect, and there are many).  My/our objection still stands.

Comment: preferred programming languages would be C# and Java.